# How to: Open the AndroidManifest.xml file and add the following as a child of the <application> element?

Tags: android, manifest

how can I do the step above?
I'm trying to the the tutorial
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html "HelloMapView" and they reccomend to Open the AndroidManifest.xml file and add the following as a child of the `<application>` element:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />.
```

how does this work?
how can I insert that in my SDK.
I'm usingEclipse SDK,Version: 3.5.2, Build id: M20100211-1343

Answer (score 2):

Open the AndroidManifest.xml file. On bottom of the page showing its content there's a row of buttons. One says `AndroidManifest.xml` .

From there you can edit directly the XML file.